# How to get email summary report via civiCRM API?

Tags: email

I am trying to get summary of email reports via civiCRM API. Unfortunately I am not able to find exact entities to get those data.
Currently I am getting `Mailing`, `MailingRecipients` and `Contact` entities. With these entities the only thing I am getting is `Intended Recipients` for the report below by counting the email recipients per email_id.

I have checked `Activity`, `Job` and `Event` entities too to get the information I need but they was not clear enough to collect information about deliveries, opens, click-throughs, bounces etc...

Could you please help about how to get this report via API? Which entities I need to use and which fields to get the related data?

[image]

Thank you

Hazal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Mailing', 'stats', [
  'mailing_id' => 10,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful.